# Creation and deletion of a file at system level

Tags: kernel, files

What happens at the **kernel level** when someone **creates or deletes a file** (*including all the housekeeping activities*)?

I have done some googling around but I couldn't find a good answer. Please excuse if it seems trivial question but as I am quite weak in Operating System concepts, I don't know the answer.
**This was an interview question.**

Comment: System level means ? at the lower level i.e. kernel level ?

Comment: at the os level

Comment: OS level refers to kernel level, right ? otherwise it seems like an ambiguous concept to me..

Comment: yes at the kernel level. Sorry for being ambiguous. i will edit

Comment: See [`man 2 unlink`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man2/unlink.2.html).

Comment: @muru is there anything detailed for the deletion and creation of file that explains in greater depth

Comment: @Coffee_lover the source code?

Comment: I am too inexperienced to understand that. i just want an overview. Rest i will dig myself.

Comment: @Coffee_lover You just want an overview, and to me, that manpage provides exactly that. The details would be dependent on the filesystem.

Comment: I am unclear about the deletion as the interviewer wanted to know the housekeeping activities too.

Comment: lets take the ubuntu for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check the system calls that are associated with the relevant commands to get low level idea of whats happening.

The tool to trace system calls is `strace`.

For example if i run `strace touch foobar.txt` to check the system calls associated with creating an empty file using `touch` the most notable system call (along with others) is :

```
open("foobar.txt", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK, 0666) = 3
```

Now read `man 2 open` to get detail idea.

Similarly if you want to trace system calls for `rm foobar.txt` the important system call (along with others) would be :

```
unlinkat(AT_FDCWD, "foobar.txt", 0)     = 0
```

Now read `man 2 unlinkat`.

Also you can save the `strace` output to a file for future diagnosis by using `-o` option :

```
strace -o s_out.txt touch foobar.txt
```

You can also track only specific system calls :

```
strace -e open touch foobar.txt
```

Also check `man strace`.

Comment: Love your answers ! Always good content.

Comment: @Coffee_lover Glad i could help :)